# Как поменять стиль у третьего элемента?

Tags: html, css

Как мне получить третий элемент p

```css
.page-block p:nth-child(3) {
  font-size: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-block">
  <div>
    <span>текст</span>
    <p>первый</p>
    <span>текст</span>
    <p>второй</p>
    <span>текст</span>
    <p>третий</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Непонимаю почему не ссрабатывает...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Селектор `:nth-child(3)` в любом случае будет указывать на третий по счету элемент.
Его объединение с `p` лишь означает, что стили сработают только если 3-м элементом окажется `<p>`

Можно использовать или `:nth-child(6)` или `p:nth-of-type(3)` или `p:last-child`

```css
.page-block p:nth-of-type(3) {
  font-size: 200%;
}

.page-block p:nth-child(6) {
  /* Можно без `p`, но так очевиднее, что пробел поставлен не случайно. */
  font-family: "Monotype Corsiva";
}

.page-block p:last-child {
  color: red;
}
                                                                     p { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="page-block">
  <div>
    <span>текст</span>
    <p>первый</p>
    <span>текст</span>
    <p>второй</p>
    <span>текст</span>
    <p>Третий</p>
  </div>
</div>
```